# User Permission on Reports and Dashboard

Tags: administration

I just have a quick question any workaround is fine or even an idea works well.My requirement is I need to find the users who have edit read delete access on reports and dashboards in the whole org. Manually checking may not be possible with profiles as well as permission sets because we have more than 261 users and 52 permission sets and 58 profiles. can anyone help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to query both Profiles and Permission Sets. Here are two queries I've used in the past:

```
SELECT Id,PermissionsEditPublicReports,PermissionsEditReports,PermissionsRunReports,PermissionsManageDashboards,PermissionsManageDynamicDashboards,PermissionsViewMyTeamsDashboards FROM PermissionSet

SELECT Id,PermissionsEditPublicReports,PermissionsEditReports,PermissionsRunReports,PermissionsManageDashboards,PermissionsManageDynamicDashboards,PermissionsViewMyTeamsDashboards FROM Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this query to find what profiles have what report permissions:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    PermissionsCreateCustomizeDashboards, 
    PermissionsCreateCustomizeReports,
    PermissionsManageDashbdsInPubFolders,
    PermissionsManageReportsInPubFolders 
FROM Profile
```

PermissionsCreateCustomizeDashboards and PermissionsCreateCustomizeReport allow you to delete reports and dashboards in your personal folder, while PermissionsManageDashbdsInPubFolders and 
PermissionsManageReportsInPubFolders allow you to delete reports and dashboards in public folders.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, Thanks for the quick reply although I'm not able to execute the query as it states "INVALID_FIELD:
PermissionsCreateCustomizeDashboards
^
ERROR at Row:3:Column:5
No such column 'PermissionsCreateCustomizeDashboards' on entity 'Profile'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names"